# jQuery conditional function dependant on whether a div exists

Tags: jquery

I have a signup form written in php. Each set of questions is within a fieldset. The fieldset which appears open when the page loads is #are_you, and it closes that fieldset and moves to the next set of questions once a response is received.

I'd like to control which fieldset appears open when the page loads. If my fieldset #additional_login (within the div #advertise_form) exists, I'd like that fieldset to appear open instead of #are_you. If #additional_login is not set, I'd like #are_you to appear open. The appearance of #additional_login to the user is controlled by a PHP if(isset()) condition.

I'm not familiar with jQuery (sorry!) so I struggled when I tried to apply the if conditions from other SO questions. The line of code which makes #are_you appear open is written with this syntax, in a .js file:

```
jQuery('#advertise_form fieldset#are_you').fadeTo(250, 1, 0).removeClass('close');
```

Please could someone advise how I would achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1 this is very very easy to find if you search.

Comment: i did say in the post, I have searched but am completely unfamiliar with jQuery and hence where to place the if condition. Also the syntax in the line of code I posted appears different!

Comment: if (jQuery('#advertise_form fieldset#additional_login').length) {
    jQuery('#additional_login').fadeTo(250, 1, 0).removeClass('close');
} else {
    jQuery('#advertise_form fieldset#are_you').fadeTo(250, 1, 0).removeClass('close');
}

Thankyou for the answers it show me how to implement. The if/else was PHP code, didn't expect to be able to do that in a .js file.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#additional_login').length) {
    $('#additional_login').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('#are_you').fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I've been able to work out how to do it with your help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can test if an element exists by using `length`:

```
if (jQuery('#additional_login').length) { 
  jQuery('#additional_login').addClass('open');
  jQuery('#are_you').addClass('close');
} else {
  jQuery('#are_you').addClass('open');
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I've been able to work out how to do it with your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use this formulation:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){ //on page ready
    if ($(element).length) { //object contains elements
    //Do what you need to do when element exists
    }
});
```

.length returns the number of elements in the jQuery Object so it's going to be a number (true) or 0 (false)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I've been able to work out how to do it with your help! :-)